# Can we load Admob ad at app launch and mirror it on other View Controllers?

Tags: iphone, admob

In our app, Admob's Ads are displayed on several View Controllers (VCs). And each VC loads it own ad. This leads to unnecessary network usage for the user.

To counter this, can we achieve something like... loading the ad when App Launches & mirroring it on VCs... this way it could have at least two benefits:

- user network would be efficiently used
- there would be no delay in displaying ad when user switches views

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't mirror the content, you could just pass the UIView between the UIViewControllers.

Put the admob code somewhere common (perhaps your app delegate) so it's only in one place. When you show a new uiviewcontroller, in it's viewWillAppear view ask the app delegate for the advert view.

Comment: yea... that seems fine... will try it out & let you know... thanks!